# Adding dropdown to bootstrap3 nav bar

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image: strap]

I'm working with bootstrap3 and django. I want to update my navbar to add a dropdown list of links in my navbar on the right . My bootstrap code:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Bob and Company</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Current Properties</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Village, Texas</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lake, Washington</a>
   </div>
                </li>


            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

so far I'm getting the screenshot. How can i fix this to get this working?

edit:

thank you, that's much better . Can the links be made verical instead of horizontal. Please see screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What is the code of the complete navbar?

Comment: I've added the complete navbar above..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it working if you do it [like this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/)?

```html
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">3</a>
  </div>
</li>
```